# How do I return a reversed string of characters?

Tags: c, reverse

I tried to reverse a string of characters in C programming language. I was given a string in my main function which serves as argument for reverse_string function when it is called such that I will return the reverse of the given string. I am not permitted to use printf as output .... It must return the reversed string

See my code below for reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse_string(char *param_1)
{
    int i;
    int n = strlen(param_1);
    char *reverse, temp;

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // printf("%c", param_1[i]);
        // printf("%c", param_1[i]);
        temp = param_1[i];
        // printf("%c", temp);
        reverse = &temp;
        printf("%c", *reverse);
    }
    return reverse;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "games";
    reverse_string(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a new array in the `main` function, big enough to hold the string *including* the null-terminator. Then pass it (and its size) as arguments to the function, which fills it in. The function makes sure to not go out of bounds (that's what the size argument is for) and adds the null-terminator.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of the function.

Comment: As for your current code, `reverse` is a pointer that you make point to the *local* variable `temp`. The lifetime of `temp` ends when the function returns, making the pointer you return immediately invalid.

Comment: You can use `malloc()` in the function to allocate a string large enough to hold the reversed string (including the null terminator). Then copy the input string to this reversed string in reverse order.

Comment: If you're not permitted to use `printf()` why is your function doing that?

Comment: I am using the printf to test if I have reversed the string.... and it showed that the string has been reversed .... however, I could not return the reversed .... if you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc()` to allocate a result string that's large enough to hold a copy of the parameter.

Then copy the characters from the parameter string to the result string in reverse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse_string(char *param_1)
{
    int i;
    int n = strlen(param_1);
    char *reverse = malloc(n+1);
    reverse[n] = '\0'; // Add null terminator

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        reverse[n-i-1] = param_1[i];
    }
    return reverse;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "games";
    char * reversed = reverse_string(str);
    printf("%s\n", reversed);
    free(reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, this solution did not pass the test cases on the platform

Comment: Sorry, I used `param_1[n]` where I meant `param_1[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

there is One way you can allocate the string on the heap

```
char *mystring = malloc(strlen(param_1)+1);
```

and then free the memory in your main function

Comment: Oops, I really meant to use `strlen()`.

Comment: Heh, I thought that I was editing my answer, not someone else's.

Comment: See what I'm trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

Promoting my solution to pass the string into the function as arguments instead, it would be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse_string(const char *original, char *reverse, size_t reverse_size)
{
    const char *original_start = original;
    const char *original_end = original + strlen(original) - 1;

    char *reverse_start = reverse;
    char *reverse_end = reverse + reverse_size - 1;

    for (/* empty */;
         original_end >= original_start &&
         reverse_start < reverse_end;
         --original_end, ++reverse_start)
    {
        *reverse_start = *original_end;
    }

    // Terminate the reverse string
    *reverse_start = '\0';

    // And return it
    return reverse;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *original = "Hello world!";
    char reverse[strlen(original) + 1];

    printf("Reverse of \"%s\" is \"%s\"\n", original,
           reverse_string(original, reverse, sizeof reverse));
}
```

Also note that I use a different technique to reverse the string, by using pointers. The parameter passing would work just as well with your technique of using indexes.